# How to join three tables - MySQL

Tags: mysql

Read it before marking it as a duplicate question.

There are three tables - invoice_order, invoice_order_item, and stock

and here is the structure of it

invoice_order

```
order_id | user_id | customer_name | order_date | order_number
1        | 1       | xyz           | y-m-d      | 0000001
```

invoice_order_item

Here order_id is a foreign key and order_item_name storing stock_id

```
order_item_id | order_id | order_item_name | order_item_quantity | order_item_price
1             | 1        | 2               | 5                   | 1000
```

Stock

```
stock_id | item_type   | item_name 
2        | goods       | Mobile
```

I'm trying to join these three tables. This is what I achieved till now

```
$query = "select * from invoice_order inner join invoice_order_item on invoice_order.order_id = invoice_order_item.order_id inner join stock on stock_id = invoice_order_item.order_item_name where invoice_order.order_id = {$order_id}";
```

The above query doesn't return the order_item_name. It outputs the stock_id instead of the item name. I need to output the name of the item instead of the stock id.

and I know code is vulnerable to SQL Injection. You can ignore it, this is only for testing purpose

Comment: sorry, my bad! Could you please check the query again! Edited the query @OcasoProtal

Comment: it is returning the stock_id instead of stock item name

Comment: Where you are checking the output ? in your program or in your MySql Console. this query will return 13 columns. you want 13 columns or only one?

Comment: I really can't understand what you mean with _it is returning the stock_id instead of stock item name_ because you are using `select *`. So everything is returned.

Comment: I'm storing stock_id in the order_item_name column (see the table structure). Considering the above example, I'm trying to output the mobile (item_name) instead of 2 (stock_id) @OcasoProtal

Comment: Then just select the columns you want to output instead of `*`: `SELECT stock.item_name FROM ...`. If you want to select more columns just add them, separated by `,`. See Lew's answer below.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  Stock.item_name
FROM invoice_order
JOIN invoice_order_item
  ON   invoice_order.order_id = invoice_order_item.order_id
JOIN Stock
  ON invoice_order_item.order_item_name = Stock.stock_id
```

[See ref](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Comment: @shakti - was there a problem with my answer?